# Is it possible to move tabs with keyboard in Notepad++

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++

Is it possible to move tabs with keyboard in Notepad++? I am not talking about moving between tabs but reorganizing tabs with keyboard only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be beneficial to have functionality you described present in Notepad++ but currently there is nothing like that implemented. If you check available commands in **Shortcut mapper**, such a command is not present. You can leave a **feature request** following the link with the same name on [Notepad++ website](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/contribute/).